# How to deduplicate mysql rows but keep max view

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have MySQL rows like this

```
id | title       | desc       | view
1  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 0
2  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 0
3  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 5
4  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 0
5  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 0
6  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 3
8  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 0
```

And i would like to keep only

```
3  | i'm a title | i'm a desc | 5
```

because this record as the max view and others are duplicates

Comment: You could use ORDER BY view DESC LIMIT 1. But what about ties?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not too big, you can use `delete` like this:

```
delete t from yourtable t join
            (select title, `desc`, max(view) as maxview
             from yourtable t
             group by title, `desc`
            ) tt
            on t.title = tt.title and
               t.`desc` = tt.`desc` and
               t.view < tt.maxview;
```

Note:  if there are multiple rows with the same maximum number of views, this will keep all of them.  Also, `desc` is a lousy name for a column because it is a SQL (and MySQL) reserved word.

EDIT:

If you have a large amount of data, often it is faster to do the `truncate`/re-`insert` approach:

```
create table temp_t as
    select t.*
    from yourtable t join
         (select title, `desc`, max(view) as maxview
          from yourtable t
          group by title, `desc`
         ) tt
         on t.title = tt.title and
            t.`desc` = tt.`desc` and
            t.view = tt.maxview;

truncate table yourtable;

insert into yourtable
    select *
    from temp_t;
```

Comment: I tried select title, `desc`, max(view) as maxview
             from yourtable t
             group by title, `desc` but it return bad id's

Comment: @JamesAmino . . . How can it return bad `id`s?  There is no id in the query.

Comment: The first answer doesn't seem to work. I can select all of the things I want to delete this way by doing replacing `DELETE FROM` with `SELECT * FROM`, but as soon as I try to delete, I get: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Comment: @eli . . . It was missing the alias after `delete`.  I always seem to do this when using `delete` with a `from` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good call. I keep winding up in the same situation and then not being able to figure out what's wrong. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand what the specific question is. The possible solutions are followed...
1) Use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` statement in mysql. Just write `UPDATE your_table_name SET view=view+1`
2) or you can run a cron job if using php to delete duplicate rows having lower value
3) If `INSERT` is necessary then you should do `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Refer to the documentation *** http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html